# Convert Cross Correlation to Probability value

Tags: probability, cross-correlation

How can I convert the [-1;1] bound cross correlation value to a probability [0;1].
Cross correlation measures the similarity of two signals / images A,B, I aim at expressing this in the probability that signal A is equal to signal B.
Essentially, cross correlation has been used in the field of bio-image processing as a similarity measure but I was wondering how cross correlation could be transformed into a probability so that I could use various probability based methods for analysis.
Is applying the square to the CC valid? Somebody have some references on that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Convert to the probability of what? Squaring would make the number fall into the range $[0,1]$ but that doesn't make it the probability of anything to do with cross-correlation. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Glen_b - please check my modified question. Does it help you understanding my aim?

Answer (score 4):

> Cross correlation measures the similarity of two signals / images A,B

Only in a very particular sense. Two things can be highly correlated but very different in size (mean, say) and scale (variation around the mean).

> I aim at expressing this in the probability that signal A is equal to signal B.

There's quite literally no direct relationship here.

Consider some $B\geq 0$.

Now take $A_1=B$. Obviously the correlation is $1$ and $P(A_1=B)=1$ by construction.

Now consider $A_2= 12 B + 10000$. The correlation is still 1 but $P(A_2=B)=0$.

So correlation is next to useless as an indication of how close to equal two things are.

If you want to measure closeness to equality, don't use correlation. (This is an error that seems to come up very frequently, and is the subject of a number of questions on this site.)

---

My suggestion is measure closeness much more directly: something like $\frac{_1}{^n}\sum (A_i-B_i)^2$, perhaps normalized to a *common* scale if you wish.

Comment: I see your point. Normalized XCC takes care of A2=12B+10000 but for probability it may be a problem. What score would you use to measure the "closeness to equality" for A and B of same size, typically 1000 values / pixels? Normalization (A2 example) is vital for me, too.

Comment: See my answer to a response to your first comment. Regarding your second - how does normalizing A and B and then finding a correlation tell you how close together the original A and B were?